# C# JSON Get data from List<>

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I am trying to make simple UWP weather app, just for learning purpose, and I am having trouble getting data from JSON.

How to get min and max temperature from public class ConsolidatedWeather?
I can get data from other classes.

Thanks a lot

**Vrime.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace _01_Weaather
{

class Vrime
{

    public async static Task<ConsolidatedWeather> ShowTemp()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var url = String.Format("https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/");
        var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();           
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ConsolidatedWeather));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        var data = (ConsolidatedWeather)ser.ReadObject(ms);

        return data;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class ConsolidatedWeather
{
    [DataMember]
    public object id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string weather_state_name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string weather_state_abbr { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string wind_direction_compass { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string created { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string applicable_date { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double min_temp { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double max_temp { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double the_temp { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double wind_speed { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double wind_direction { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double air_pressure { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double? visibility { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int predictability { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Parent
{
    [DataMember]

    public string title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string location_type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int woeid { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string latt_long { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Source
{
    [DataMember]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string slug { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string url { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int crawl_rate { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{[DataMember]
    public List<ConsolidatedWeather> consolidated_weather { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string time { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string sun_rise { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string sun_set { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string timezone_name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Parent parent { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Source> sources { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string location_type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int woeid { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string latt_long { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string timezone { get; set; }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
 namespace _01_Weaather
 {
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    double min;
    double max;


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();



    }

    private async void BtnPrikaz_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       ConsolidatedWeather cWeather = await Vrime.ShowTemp();
        min =cWeather.min_temp;
        max = cWeather.max_temp;
        txtTemp.Text = String.Format(min.ToString() + "\n"+ max.ToString());


    }

}
```

Comment: from where you are getting the values for min and max as inputs to the function?

Comment: From class ConsolidateWeather.

Comment: They are always zero(0).

Comment: you dont understand my question.,  await Vrime.ShowTemp(min, max); what is min and max here

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question :(

Comment: your ShowTemp methods requires min and max as parameters. what are the input for those?

Comment: It should get input from weather api.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143616/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-toni0123).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your deserializing is not on the correct object. It should be on RootObject. As the JSON retured by weather API returns data for future dates as well so if you need Min and Max temperature for today then below is the sample code.

```
public async Task<RootObject> ShowTemp()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var url = String.Format("https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/");
        var response = await http.GetAsync(url);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        var data = (RootObject)ser.ReadObject(ms);

        return data;
    }

    public async Task<ConsolidatedWeather> GetWeatherForToday()
    {
        RootObject ro = await ShowTemp();
        ConsolidatedWeather todayWeather = ro.consolidated_weather.FirstOrDefault();
        return todayWeather;

        // for getting min and max
        // todayWeather.min_temp;
        // todayWeather.max_temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing the data types of the attributes min & max temperature to float and you are using wrong object type to deserialize. use your root object. Also, i'd recommend using something like restsharp for api consumption. thats going to make your life 2X easier.

Comment: Can you write how to deserialize root object?

Comment: follow the instruction on the link. it pretty much says it all. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm